# rtl8111/8168b doesn't work after upgrade linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, drivers, arch-linux

my computer has a ethernet controller: realtek semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 06)

my computer is installed archlinux. Before I upgrade kernel, it worked well, but when I upgrade kernel to 3.6.9-1-ARCH, it doesn't work!

The ethernet controller could be found in "lspci". But eth0 doesn't appear in "ip addr" or "ifconfig". there is only "lo"

would someone could help me? thank you!

Comment: Not a programming question.

Comment: What happens when you try to set `eth0` as up?  `# ip link set eth0 up`, then try `ifconfig` or `ip addr`.  It could be that the module was misplaced post-upgrade.